# Difference between tsconfig.json and tsconfig.build.json

Tags: typescript, npm, monorepo

Many guides (e.g. [1](https://blog.frankdejonge.nl/setting-up-a-typescript-mono-repo-for-scoped-packages/), [2](https://github.com/Quramy/npm-ts-workspaces-example)) on setting up NPM monorepos for a TypeScript project instruct having two separate files at the root level, `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.build.json`.

What are the differences between these files? Can they be combined into one file `tsconfig.json`? I've also seen `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.base.json` in other posts, are `.app`/`.build`/`.base` built-in signifiers, or can you put arbitrary words (e.g. `tsconfig.foo.json`)?

Comment: adding anything in that area has no official meaning, they can be imported/based from though

Comment: Did you try _looking_ at the differences between them? Typically one will just extend the other and add things like file inclusions/exclusions that are narrower than you'd need for e.g. linting or testing.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the articles referenced. [One of them](https://blog.frankdejonge.nl/setting-up-a-typescript-mono-repo-for-scoped-packages/) includes text which describes what the file is for: "First up is a top-level config file (tsconfig.build.json) that we'll use as configuration baseline."

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did read them, and that excerpt is not sufficient. `tsconfig.json` is also a top-level config used as a configuration baseline, with contents often similar to `tsconfig.build.json`. It's not made clear whether having both files is necessary; whether they differ in the fields they accept; whether `tsc` integrates them differently; whether this approach is for monorepos specifically etc. ***or*** if the distinction is instead purely conceptual with no special effect on functionality. It sounds like it's the latter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I did look at the differences between them, and found that their contents overlap across guides, making me suspect that the differences between them are conceptual / organizational rather than there being built-in implications for tools like `tsc`, which motivated me to post my question.

Comment: My comment was not an answer. It was meant as a prompt to get you to read the rest of the article, which continues, "Our main top-level configuration file `tsconfig.json` will extend our build configuration. `{ "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json", ...`" So the build file contains repo-wide configuration, and each project within can use the same values or override them as needed. Is that "purely conceptual"? I guess? But it makes keeping a core set of configuration properties the same across the monorepo much easier. But that's like, my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `tsc` looks up `tsconfig.json` in the current folder. If not found, then the parent folder, the parent of parent folder, and so on. As well as resolution mechanism of `package.json` if you are familiar with Node.js.

When you need different configurations, multiple files can be defined. That's why your project has `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.build.json`. Usually, `tsconfig.json` is used by default and `tsconfig.build.json` is used with `tsc -b`, which means only compiling those out-of-date files to save time. In order to make those files easy to be maintained, you can use `extends` in them. Refer to [TS offical website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends).

You can also put arbitrary words or any file names like `my-best-config.json`, as long as sending it to tsc explicitly. Another good example is `webpack`, which also has very similar configuration way.

Answer (score 0):

The official TypeScript documentation shows how to use the configuration file.

In general, when TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript, it uses a configuration file that sometimes you want to transpile some part of your project instead of transpiling all at once.

For example for production environment transpile the whole **src** folder and not the **test** folder, but in development environment you want to transpile src and the test folder.

You can review what the official documentation explains about this in the following link:

[TypeScript Oficial documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html)